# Im getting a package not found error for firebase on my NewBlogPost component

Tags: reactjs, firebase, error-handling

everything on the app to this point has worked im trying to set up the section for the user to post a blog to the site and im not complying.I know the issuse is in where im calling the firebase.database i just dont know what im dont wrong

could it be an issue with the rules set in firedase or the way the data structures are set up. I am new to setting those up and not sure if im doing that right either
[image: this is an image of the error]

here is the code I wrote to create the new blog post

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import firebase from "firebase";
import { UserAuth } from "../context/authContext";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";




const NewBlogPost = () => {
    const auth = useContext(UserAuth);
    const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
    const [content, setContent] = useState("");
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
    const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState("");

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        // Upload the image to Firebase Storage
        const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(`blog_images/${image.name}`);
        const snapshot = await storageRef.put(image);
        const url = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
        // Create a new blog post in the Firebase Realtime Database
        const blogRef = firebase.database().ref("blogs").push();
        const blog = {
            title,
            content,
            imageUrl: url,
            authorId: auth.currentUser.uid,
            authorName: auth.currentUser.displayName,
            timestamp: Date.now(),
        };
        await blogRef.set(blog);
        // Reset the form
        setTitle("");
        setContent("");
        setImage(null);
        setImageUrl("");
    };

    const handleImageChange = (event) => {
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        setImage(file);
        setImageUrl(URL.createObjectURL(file));
    };

    if (!auth.currentUser) {
        // Redirect to login page if user is not authenticated
        return <Navigate to="/login" />;
    }
```

Comment: i forgot to add what my rules look like 
```{
  "rules": {
    "blog_posts": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "auth.uid === '********'",
      "$post_id": {
        ".write": "auth.uid === '*******'",
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['title', 'content', 'author'])",
        


      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which version of firebase is used? Your code is for firebase v8, for v9+ code and `import`s will be different.

Comment: I am using Firebase v9

Comment: Thats the issue. Here is a [migration guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade).

Comment: ok i reworked it with v9 syntax thanks ..... i have new errors to work with now lol being new to this stuff is hard